Custom nexus apt repository setup causing error
I have a hosted apt repo configured in Sonatype nexus which I am trying to configure in my local Debian machine.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cust-repository.list file:
deb [trusted=yes] https://nexusrepourl.org/repository/apt/ bullseye main

When I try to do a apt-get update, getting below error:
Err:7 https://nexusrepourl.org/repository/apt bullseye/main amd64 Packages
  404  dists/bullseye/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz [IP: xx.xx.xx.xxx 443]
Ign:8 https://nexusrepourl.org/repository/apt bullseye/main all Packages
Ign:9 https://nexusrepourl.org/repository/apt bullseye/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://nexusrepourl.org/repository/apt/dists/bullseye/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  dists/bullseye/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz [IP: xx.xx.xx.xxx 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have removed all files from /var/lib/apt/lists/ as mentioned in official documentation https://help.sonatype.com/en/apt-repositories.html
Anyone please help me understand how to get around this. Thank you.

Did you remove that line from the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cust-repository.list or delete the file altogether if there was nothing else in it before running apt-get update?
